# sql: count number of appearances in other table

Tags: sql, count

I have two tables `tab1` and `tab2`.

```
tab1:

id | name | var1 | ...
-------------------------
1  | a    | ...  | ...
2  | b    | ...  | ...
3  | c    | ...  | ...
4  | d    | ...  | ...


tab2:

id | name | var1 | ...
-------------------------
1  | a    | ...  | ...
2  | a    | ...  | ...
3  | a    | ...  | ...
4  | b    | ...  | ...
5  | b    | ...  | ...
```

I'd like to get all the entries in `tab1` plus as an additional column `appearances` containing the number of appearances of each value of `tab1.name` in `tab2`.

I tried something like this with a subquery but could not get it to work:

```sql
SELECT 
  *,
  (SELECT * FROM tab2 ??? ) AS `appearances`
FROM
  tab1
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please [add a tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by querying  count of each appearance by name like this:

```
SELECT 
  t1.*,
  (SELECT count(*) FROM tab2 where name = t1.name ) AS `appearances`
FROM
 tab1 t1;
```

Answer (score 3):

A left join combined with an aggregation should work here:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.name,
    t1.var1,
    COUNT(t2.name) AS num_occurrences
FROM tab1 t1
LEFT JOIN tab2 t2
    ON t1.name = t2.name
GROUP BY
    t1.id,
    t1.name,
    t1.var1;
```

Note that depending on your database you might be able to just `GROUP BY` the `id` column of the first table (the other columns in the select clause being functionally dependent on the `id`).  If you don't like listing many columns in `GROUP BY`, you could also aggregate the second table separately in a subquery, and then join to that:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.name,
    t1.var1,
    COALESCE(t2.cnt, 0) AS num_occurrences
FROM tab1 t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM tab2
    GROUP BY name
) t2
    ON t1.name = t2.name;
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to [GroupBy](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) and [Count](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html)

```
Select a.Id, a.Name, Count(b.Id) as appereances
FROM tab1 a
    LEFT JOIN tab2 b on a.Name = b.Name
GROUP BY a.Id, a.Name
```